# If statements are conflicting with each other - how to recitfy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement

I have two `if` statements and they both are conflicting with each other.

By default I can do filter by `Dates` and a `Drop Down` list from this `if` Statement:

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime toDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        if (dateFilter.Contains('~'))
        {
            fromDate = dateFilter.Split('~')[0] == "" ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dateFilter.Split('~')[0]);
            toDate = dateFilter.Split('~')[1] == "" ? DateTime.MaxValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dateFilter.Split('~')[1]);
        }

        filteredTracks = DataRepository.GetTracks()
                                 .Where(c => (trackFilter == "" || c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
                                             &&
                                             (fromDate == DateTime.MinValue || fromDate < c.Date)
                                             &&
                                             (toDate == DateTime.MaxValue || c.Date < toDate)
        );
```

but cannot do normal filtering records using this `if` statement, if the above one is being used:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            var isTrackSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]);
            filteredTracks = DataRepository.GetTracks()
               .Where(c => isTrackSearchable && c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()));
        }
        else
        {
            filteredTracks = allTracks;
        }
```

is it possible to have both of these to work?

Any help would be a great help :)

Comment: Place second if-statement in first?

Comment: thanks, i tried that before posting it in here and vice versa.

Comment: maybe posting the full method handling this would be great and could you be more precise at how you want it to work?

Comment: You can simply use something like `filteredTracks = filteredTracks.Where(...`, filtering the results of first if-statement.

Comment: @Andrei thanks, let me try that

Comment: @Andrei, man you killed it. thanks for that it's working now :) How can +rep you?

Comment: @user3679123, great it helped. turned into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases you can reuse the same query, conditionally adding `Where` clauses. E.g. for the second if-statement you can do just:

```
filteredTracks = filteredTracks.Where(...
```

Where `filteredTracks` already contains a result of first if-statement.

Comment: you're absolutely correct - Got it! thanks for the information and your help again :)